# MySQL pivot table for joined rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

There are 3 tables `Users`, junction table `UserItems` and `Items`. So the query

```sql
SELECT `u`.`Name` as `User`, `i`.`Name` as `Item`
FROM `Users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `UserItems` `ui` ON `ui`.`UserID` = `u`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `Items` `i` ON `i`.`ID` = `ui`.`ItemID`;
```

produces the result

```
+------+-------+
| User | Item  |
+------+-------+
| John | Book  |
| John | Apple |
| Mary | Pen   |
+------+-------+
```

Desirable result

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| User | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| John | Book   | Apple  | NULL   |
| Mary | Pen    | NULL   | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I don't mind column headers to be hardcoded, so the query should handle cases when user has up to 3 items and ignore the rest. But since there is no way to distinguish items in select, solutions for other similar questions do not work here.

For now I ended up with the slow query

```sql
SELECT `u`.`Name`,
(
  SELECT `i`.`Name`
  FROM `UserItems` `ui`
  JOIN `Items` `i` ON `i`.`ID` = `ui`.`ItemID`
  WHERE `ui`.`UserID` = `u`.`ID`
  ORDER BY `ui`.`ItemID`
  LIMIT 0, 1
) AS `Item 1`,
(
  SELECT `i`.`Name`
  FROM `UserItems` `ui`
  JOIN `Items` `i` ON `i`.`ID` = `ui`.`ItemID`
  WHERE `ui`.`UserID` = `u`.`ID`
  ORDER BY `ui`.`ItemID`
  LIMIT 1, 1
) AS `Item 2`,
(
  SELECT `i`.`Name`
  FROM `UserItems` `ui`
  JOIN `Items` `i` ON `i`.`ID` = `ui`.`ItemID`
  WHERE `ui`.`UserID` = `u`.`ID`
  ORDER BY `ui`.`ItemID`
  LIMIT 2, 1
) AS `Item 3`
FROM `Users` `u`
```

Perhaps, there is a better way to achieve the same?

MySQL 5.7.12 is used.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: This is used as a View for external reporting service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
select u.name as user, 
    max(case when ui.rn = 1 then i.name end) as item1,
    max(case when ui.rn = 2 then i.name end) as item2,
    max(case when ui.rn = 3 then i.name end) as item3
from users u
left join (
    select ui.*,
        (select count(*) from useritems ui1 where ui1.userid = ui.userid and ui1.itemid <= ui.itemid) as rn
    from useritems ui
) ui on ui.userid = u.id and ui.rn <= 3
left join items i on i.id = ui.itemid
group by u.id
```

The idea is to use a subqueries to rank items that belong to the same user, and then use that information to pivot the dataset.

In MySQL 8.0, we would use `row_number()` instead of the subquery:

```
select u.name as user, 
    max(case when ui.rn = 1 then i.name end) as item1,
    max(case when ui.rn = 2 then i.name end) as item2,
    max(case when ui.rn = 3 then i.name end) as item3
from users u
left join (
    select ui.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by userid order by itemid) as rn
    from useritems ui
) ui on ui.userid = u.id and ui.rn <= 3
left join items i on i.id = ui.itemid
group by u.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't provided performance improvement in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way: transform it programmatically from the two column result.

MySQL also has aggregate function group_concat to merge records into single columns, although it does not make separate columns you wanted.

```
SELECT `u`.`Name` as `User`, group_concat(`i`.`Name` SEPARATOR ' | ') as `Item`
FROM `Users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `UserItems` `ui` ON `ui`.`UserID` = `u`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `Items` `i` ON `i`.`ID` = `ui`.`ItemID`
GROUP by User;
```

Comment: To my mind, this solution is a step backwards

Answer (score 0):

You approach is fine, but I would phrase it differently:

```
select name,
from (select u.name,
           (select ui.userid, ui.itemid
            from useritems ui
            order by ui.itemid
            limit 1 offset 0
           ) as itemid1,
           (select ui.userid, ui.itemid
            from useritems ui
            order by ui.itemid
            limit 1 offset 1
           ) as itemid2,
           (select ui.userid, ui.itemid
            from useritems ui
            order by ui.itemid
            limit 1 offset 2
           ) as itemid3
      from users u
     ) ui left join
     items i1
     on i1.id = ui.itemid1 left join
     items i2
     on i2.id = ui.itemid2 left join
     items i3
     on i3.id = ui.itemid3;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of indexes on `userItems(userId, itemId)` and `items(id)`.  It is likely that you already have those indexes.

You can also do this with a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` hack.  Assuming you don't have too many items and they don't have commas:

```
SELECT u.Name as User, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY i.id), ',', 1) as item_1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY i.id), ',', 2), ',', -1) as item_2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY i.id), ',', 3), ',', -1) as item_3
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN
     UserItems ui
     ON ui.UserID = u.ID LEFT JOIN
     Items i
     ON i.ID = ui.ItemID
GROUP BY u.Name
```

Comment: Even after fixing syntax errors first query provides different result than the original query.